# How can I close the IPython embeded shell from the embedding code?

Tags: python, tkinter, ipython

I'm embedding a IPython shell on a Tk application.

This works well for automatically enabling the GUI eventloop, and you can add some default configurations too. The `self._ishell` object has the IPython instance.

```py
from IPython.core.getipython import get_ipython
from IPython.terminal.embed import InteractiveShellEmbed
from traitlets.config import Config as IPython_Config

def startIPython(self):
    if get_ipython() is None:
        self._ishell = InteractiveShellEmbed.instance()
    else:
        self._ishell = InteractiveShellEmbed()
    self._ishell.enable_gui('tk')
    self._ishell(
        local_ns={"string": "Some String"}
    )
    self._ishell = None
```

Since this is integrated on the GUI, the Tk event loop and the IPython "event loop" are running on parallel.

To avoid zombie processes, I refuse to exit from the GUI if IPython is running. I can detect this since `self._ishell is not None`.

How can I kill the IPython event loop from the outside, that is, from that embedding instance?

Using `self._ishell.exiter()` will exit from `IPython` on the next input. Is there a way to quit immediately?